# redirect external subdomain traffic

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, dns

I have apache installed on one of my server on two different ports, all http requests are handled by the apache on the default (80). Now I have a subdomain for a domain and I want the request for the sub domain to be handled by the apache on the other port (10024).

I've tried using

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^sub.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www.domain.com:10024/dir/page.php [R,L]
```

but dont get the required result.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing HTTP_REFERER to HTTP_HOST and rewrite rule to:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/$ http://www.domain.com:10024/dir/page.php [R,L]
```